# Best tool for REST API generation when using Svelte & TypeScript with Firebase

Tags: api, rest, firebase

It seems unproductive that I have to write REST backends for virtually every collection in my Firestore DB. I figured, this must be a solved problem and there has to be an existing solution which allows me to quickly click together an API which allows me to customise the queries, mutations and what fields to expose through JSON?